# How to use L1 Regularization for LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS in spark MLlib

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

The [official documentation says](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS) that: *L2 regularization are used by default*

How can I use L1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MLLib you have to set optimizer updater as follows:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS
import org.apache.spark.mllib.optimization.L1Updater

val lr: LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS = ???
val training: RDD[LabeledPoint] = ???

lr.optimizer.setUpdater(new L1Updater)
lr.run(training)
```

In ML you can set `setElasticNetParam` to 1.0:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.ml.regression.LinearRegression

val training: DataFrame = ???

val lr = new LinearRegression().setElasticNetParam(1.0)
lr.fit(training)
```